# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS prevent Logout

Tags: 22.04, users, lts, logout, kiosk

is there a possibility to prevent user from logout.
I use the system as a KIOSK device for Web Browsing and Information.

Thanks
Sofa

Comment: One fairly easy option: https://mir-server.io/docs/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk